# type hint returns NameError: name 'datetime' not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I have this function below;

```
def time_in_range(start, end, x):
    """Return true if x is in the range [start, end]"""
    if start <= end:
        return start <= x <= end
    else:
        return start <= x or x <= end
```

The function parameters are all datetime type. I want to add typing hint to the function. This is what I did;

```
def time_in_range(start: datetime, end: datetime, x: datetime) -> bool:
    """Return true if x is in the range [start, end]"""
    if start <= end:
        return start <= x <= end
    else:
        return start <= x or x <= end
```

I get the error `NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined`. What is the proper way to add typing for this function?

I am using python v3.7

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to import `datetime`, or use a string (remember, it is just an hint).

```py
>>> def f(x: datetime):
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
>>> def f(x: 'datetime'):
...     pass
...
>>>
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> def f(x: datetime):
...     pass
...
>>>
```

Python 3.7.4

--

UPDATE. For a slightly different version of this issue import `__future__.annotations`

```
from __future__ import annotations

def f(dto: Dto):
    pass

class Dto:
    pass
```

This would otherwise fail in the function reference to the Dto class. Python4 will have this as the default behaviour. For now, the import must be the first statement of the file.

Tested in Python 3.8.10.

See: https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/

Answer (score 24):

Either `import datetime` and use `datetime.datetime` as hint, or `from datetime import datetime` and use `datetime` as hint.

Comment: `from datetime import datetime` worked for me

Comment: @Sameen yes, both are equivalent, there's a `datetime` object inside another module named `datetime`

Comment: Using `datetime.datetime` as a hint yields an `AttributeError` for me, but `from datetime import datetime` works. Don't ask me why.